# Unknow multiple key values for $_POST variable?

Tags: php, post

I have this page that's gonna post to my php page and the post is gonna arrive like this:

```
namexxxxxxx= <name>
stringidxxxxxxxx= <stringid>
```

The "xxxxxx" is a random number, but is the same number to both keys.
So what I'm doing:

```
$keys= array_keys($_POST);
$idNumber= substr($keys[0], 4);

$name= $_POST["name".$idNumber];
$stringId= $_POST["stringId".$idNumber];
```

This way I can get the values easily. Now comes the hard part(for me at least):
The post comes from a page where the user can select from lots of items in a list, and the reason the keys have a number is that the user can select as many items as he wants to.
So let's say he chose 3 items, so i must handle a post like this:

```
nameXXXXX: name1;
stringIdxxxx: stringId1;

nameXXXXX: name2;
stringIdxxxx: stringId2;

nameXXXXX: name2;
stringIdxxxx: stringId2;
```

So how can I fetch the post keys in order to get all the different data and handle each one of it as the first one?
Thank You!

Comment: Refactoring this into a sane POST format is not an option...? `item[1][name]=...&item[1][id]=...&item[2][name]=..`

Comment: @deceze already got it working with Shailesh's answer. But thank you very much for your time bro =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $keys= array_keys($_POST);
 for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++)
 {
    $idNumber= substr($keys[$i], 4);

    $name= $_POST["name".$idNumber];
    $stringId= $_POST["stringId".$idNumber];
 }
```

Using Loop you can iterate all array elements and gettting values.

Comment: this worked, but it returns 2 results for each number(name and stringId), on the first return i can manage to fetch both, but the loop returns the second anyway, is there a way to skip the second value for every result?

Answer (score 2):

Use `[]` notation:

```
<input name="name[]" value="1" />
<input name="name[]" value="2" />
<input name="name[]" value="3" />
```

After that `$_POST['name']` will be an array, containing values `[1, 2, 3]`.

Further more you can define indexes:

```
<input name="name[200]" value="1" />
<input name="name[400]" value="2" />
<input name="name[700]" value="3" />
```

After that `$_POST['name']` will be an array, containing values `[200 => 1, 400 => 2, 700 => 3]`.

Comment: But the inputs are dinamically generated, I can't know for sure how many and in which order the user is gonna pick.

Comment: Order of fields is the same as they appear on the form. How many of what? Of fields? `sizeof($_POST['name'])` will give you number of fields.